# How do I remove a duplicated global application menu?

Tags: 12.04, unity, appmenu

I encounter this event at least three times per day:
Following a suddenly one second of black screen, a duplicated global menu will appear. I have to reboot to remove it, but this event will happen after several hours.

[image]

Ubuntu 12.04LTS amd64 Unity